# bcrypt compare two other strings and returns true

Tags: javascript

I am programming a refresh token jwt in Node.js.
After logging in, it hashes them and saves them in the database.

1. First token:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NjA4NTksImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ2NDQ1OX0.p6LTPotLugZ-JWp4Xmt4chwWxtqqZRXuXDBhDdqLsLI

2. Secound token:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NjEzMjIsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ2NDkyMn0.qMzg99DE1DvDjoMXeK08l12SlfbQd7GUSHEF5X8Mt4w

Bcrypt hash:

$2b$10$RTZbH4UONRaBnam.oALmhuIs/veX.h7e3CeMlmQjk9GVC4kKPGsBO

The two tokens are different and bcrypt shows, in two cases, that they match the encoded hash.

I also debugged this through the site and the same thing - both different strings show they match with the hash - why?

These are my hashing methods:

```
  /**
   * generate hash from password or string
   * @param {string} password
   * @returns {Promise<string>}
   */
  static async generateHash(password: string): Promise<string> {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  }

  /**
   * validate text with hash
   * @param {string} password
   * @param {string} hash
   * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
   */
  static async validateHash(password: string, hash?: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, hash || '');
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bcrypt is limited to 72 character "password"

Your "passwords" are 220 characters long, and the first 147 are identical (since that's just the header and the first part of the content of the JWT that is identical in both cases)

So, your code is only "hashing" the first, identical, 72 characters