# why these 2 strings are identical for bcrypt?

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

`refreshToken` is a string that is checked to see if it is in line with encoding.

`currentHashedRefreshToken` is currently an encoded token.

`isRefreshTokenMatching` is a boolean variable that compares if the encoded string matches bcrypt.

```
{
  refreshToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NzM4NTcsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ3NzQ1N30.o9nEeH4V7PZ61jWRG7-7epH79Vi9HJQWorvx5A37q4o'
}
{
  currentHashedRefreshToken: '$2b$10$ZYsrh1xu3icprkvRI0OksuBx6hrfOs9lmO7oZ2qqM6pFCLDiVaQrq'
}
{ isRefreshTokenMatching: true }
```

secound:

```
{
  refreshToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NzUzOTgsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ3ODk5OH0.iHRhFmtgRbsgTv9uC7VDaT_bU1tHxdlCjHDCjfmxeKA'
}
{
  currentHashedRefreshToken: '$2b$10$ZYsrh1xu3icprkvRI0OksuBx6hrfOs9lmO7oZ2qqM6pFCLDiVaQrq'
}
{ isRefreshTokenMatching: true }
```

why both refresh tokens detect that they match if they are different and different?

Here are my methods for hashing and decoding:

```
  /**
   * generate hash from password or string
   * @param {string} password
   * @returns {Promise<string>}
   */
  static async generateHash(password: string): Promise<string> {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  }

  /**
   * validate text with hash
   * @param {string} password
   * @param {string} hash
   * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
   */
  static async validateHash(password: string, hash?: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, hash || '');
  }
```

Comment: the code you posted isn't doing anything with the data that you listed that is supposedly related to it.  can you post a more complete example of what you are trying to do here?

Comment: `currentHashedRefreshToken` is the hashed password used in creating the `refreshToken` - of course they will be the same, and the tokens will be different since they have a different issued at and expiry time

Comment: @JaromandaX so I have two different refreshToken and one currentHashedRefreshToken - so this is okay, that two other string has the same for bcrypt?

Comment: none of the code you've shown has anything to do with `refreshToken` ... other than the fact that the `currentHashedRefreshToken` is actually (I'm guessing since I can't decrypt it) the hashed password used for creating the `refreshToken` - the value of `refreshToken` has nothing to do with `isRefreshTokenMatching` based on the code you've shown - again, you'll have to show how `isRefreshTokenMatching` is calculated if you want more information

Comment: Also, this looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript, although I don't think the difference is relevant to the question.

Comment: See my answer in your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847747/bcrypt-compare-two-other-strings-and-returns-true